# WP Polylang как задать hreflang?

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

Есть мультиязычный сайт, в странице которого выводяться метатеги с hreflang -ами от Polylang плагина. Вопрос, как поменять с en на en-in ?
[image: hreflang]

В [документации написано](https://polylang.pro/doc/configure-the-languages/), что замена кода страны осуществляется с админки. (6. Language code) но что-то при изменении ничего не происходит. Оно так и остается en. Кто-то сталкивался, может что-то посоветовать ? *не хочется править файлы самого плагина.`frontend-filters-links.php`

```
            /**
             * Filters the list of rel hreflang attributes
             *
             * @since 2.1
             *
             * @param array $hreflangs Array of urls with language codes as keys
             */
            $hreflangs = apply_filters( 'pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', $hreflangs );

            foreach ( $hreflangs as $lang => $url ) {
                printf( '<link rel="alternate" href="%s" hreflang="%s" />' . "\n", esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( $lang ) );
            }
        }
    }


///////////////
        // Outputs the section only if there are translations ( $urls always contains self link )
        if ( ! empty( $urls ) && count( $urls ) > 1 ) {
            $languages = array();
            $hreflangs = array();

            // Prepare the list of languages to remove the country code
            foreach ( array_keys( $urls ) as $locale ) {
                $split = explode( '-', $locale );
                $languages[ $locale ] = reset( $split );
            }

            $count = array_count_values( $languages );

            foreach ( $urls as $locale => $url ) {
                $lang = $count[ $languages[ $locale ] ] > 1 ? $locale : $languages[ $locale ]; // Output the country code only when necessary
                $hreflangs[ $lang ] = $url;
            }
```

*Код работает правильно если есть доп. английский. Если добавлять en-ZA (Новозеландский), то код языка сработает верно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мое почтение за детальный поиск в файлах плагина, но нужно было посмотреть чуть ниже найденного куска кода, т.к. там используется фильтр pll_rel_hreflang_attributes

Comment: добавил в вопрос этот фильтр, но каким образом это поможет ответу не пойму... Желательно не править плагин, поскольку с его обновлением владельцем сайта, это всё упадет.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Это значит что за него можно зацепиться и изменить необходый Вам вывод. [Хуки в WordPress (фильтры и события)](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/hooks)

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал, но как воспользоваться, что-то не доходит.

Comment: Пробовал, что-то на подобии ` add_filter( 'pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', polylang_corrected_hreflangs', 10, 1 );
function polylang_corrected_hreflangs( $hreflangs ) {
    $hreflangs[0]    = 'en-in';
    return $hreflangs;
}` но не сработало

Comment: Там же коммент в приведенном Вами коде `array $hreflangs Array of urls with language codes as keys`, то есть там массив вида `['en' => 'http://test.loc', 'pt' => 'http://test.loc/pt']`.

Comment: Как поменять значение ключа этого массива? `$hreflangs[en] = 'en-in';` меняет 'en' => 'en-in' а надо ['en-in' => 'http://test.loc',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
add_filter('pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', function($hreflangs) {
    $en_hreflang_link = $hreflangs['en'];
    $hreflangs['en-in'] = $en_hreflang_link;
    unset($hreflangs['en']);

    return $hreflangs;
}, 10, 1);
```

Что получается. Вы вешаете фильтр на `pll_rel_hreflang_attributes`, внутри сохраняете в переменную `$en_hreflang_link` значение ключа `$hreflangs['en']`, то есть ссылку. Затем добавляете новый ключ с нужной вам локалью `$hreflangs['en-in']` и присваиваете ему велью переменной `$en_hreflang_link`, то есть ссылку. Удаляете из массива элемент `$hreflangs['en']` при помощи `unset()`.

> А как сделать что б этот элемент с hreflang оставался на первой
> позиции ? * просто у меня следующий костыль плагина который добавляет
> x-default ориентируется именно что б hreflang по умолчанию был тем что
> идет на первой позиции

Ну здесь есть наверное несколько опций как это сделать. Если важен порядок только для первого элемента, то можно сделать `array_reverse($hreflangs)` (элементы будут возвращены в обратном порядке, таким образо последний элемент станет первым), либо можете поменять немножко код таким образом:

```
add_filter('pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', function($hreflangs) {
    $en_hreflang_link = $hreflangs['en'];
    $my_hreflangs['en-in'] = $en_hreflang_link;
    unset($hreflangs['en']);

    return array_merge($my_hreflangs, $hreflangs);
}, 10, 1);
```

Comment: А как сделать что б этот элемент с `hreflang` оставался на первой позиции ? * просто у меня следующий костыль плагина который добавляет `x-default` ориентируется  именно что б `hreflang` по умолчанию был тем что идет на первой позиции